# PowerShell: function interpolation

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm a PowerShell beginner. What is the reason that one should use `$()` to get Write-Host to evaluate this function?

I could not find a reason for this from the documentation.

```
PS C:\Temp> Write-Host [math]::round($diff.TotalMinutes, 2)
[math]::round 751681,102679735 2

___________________________________________________________________________________________________________

PS C:\Temp> Write-Host $([math]::round($diff.TotalMinutes, 2))
751681,1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the dollar sign and use just

```
Write-Host ([math]::round($diff.TotalMinutes, 2))
```

The brackets are needed for the parser so that first the expression is evaluated and then bound to parameter `-Object`.
There are some rules when parser expects that the string will be expression and when it treats it as a string and passes it to the command without evaluating. More info can be found in [PowerShell in Action](http://www.manning.com/payette2/).

Dollar sign is needed if there are more expressions separated by `;`

```
Write-Host $(get-date; 1; "test")
```